# Java spring MVC annotated custom date json serializer is being ignored

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a Java 1.7 app running Spring MVC 3.1.x, with hibernate, backed by SQL Server 2008, using Jackson 1.9.x for serialisation of domain objects to JSON.

The project structure is just a standard Spring MVC setup, nothing special, I have a controller, service and repository hooked up using hibernate to SQL Server. Oh and I'm using Maven 3.3.9 for dependency management.

My issue is that the date field is not being formatted correctly. The data returned from my end point just does the default format to an epoch number.

So to handle this I created a custom serializer:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonProcessingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonSerializer;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializerProvider;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class JsonDateSerialiser extends JsonSerializer<Date> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
        String formattedDate = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
        jsonGenerator.writeString(formattedDate);
    }
}
```

Then I annotated my domain class getter with the class:

```
import my.package.JsonDateSerialiser;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity()
@Table(name = "tableName")
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class MyDomainObject {

    @Id
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateTimeOfEvent;

    @JsonSerialize(using = JsonDateSerialiser.class)
    public Date getDateTimeOfEvent() {
        return dateTimeOfEvent;
    }

    public void setDateTimeOfEvent(Date dateTimeOfEvent) {
        this.dateTimeOfEvent = dateTimeOfEvent;
    }
}
```

But the annotation is being ignored.

Here is my controller stripped right back (minus imports):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/some/data")
public class MyDataController {

  @Autowired
  private MyDataService myDataService;

  @RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        value = "/{eventType}",
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
  )
  public @ResponseBody List<MyDomainObject> getDataForEventType(@PathVariable("eventType") String eventType){
      return myDataService.getDataForEventType(eventType);
  }

}
```

I've tried putting it on the field with no joy.
I've tried annotating the custom serialiser with `@Entity` which did nothing.
When debugging the custom serialiser `serialize` method is not hit.

I am getting JSON data back from the service, but it just has a number for the date.

Example of the JSON returned:

```
[
 {
    "dateTimeOfEvent": 1478701160000
 },
 {
    "dateTimeOfEvent": 1478701515000
 }
]
```

I've also looked at various different answers on stack overflow and other web resources which have mostly just pointed me back to the code I have above. Any help here would be great, thanks.

UPDATE

I've since discovered some bean configurations for the jackson `ObjectMapper` and `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` which could be overriding my class annotations maybe?

Bear in mind I'm working with legacy code so dont judge any deprecated usage here please. Here is the config snippet:

```
<bean id="jaxbAnnIntrospector" class="org.codehaus.jackson.xc.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector" />
<bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper">
    <property name="serializationConfig.annotationIntrospector" ref="jaxbAnnIntrospector" />
    <property name="deserializationConfig.annotationIntrospector" ref="jaxbAnnIntrospector" />
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"
              p:objectMapper-ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

UPDATE:

The bean config was the key. I just needed to add a date format to the object mapper and that was used global in the application. I'll add a proper answer with the full set of beans. I also just removed all domain class level annotated serializers as they were ignored because of the application level beans.

Comment: Can you show us where you expect the object to be serialized to JSON (your controller) and the actual JSON you see?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis Does that mean you can't reproduce the issue by using the domain object code and the serializer with a standard spring mvc 3.1 app with similar dependencies as mentioned, or do you mean there is not enough detail here to do that? I didnt want to make the question too noisy by including an entire application. Can you not assume the app works and just concentrate on the serialiser aspect?

Comment: _I can't reproduce this_ means I took the code you've posted here, made the minimal assumptions about your configuration, and tried to execute it. I got the result `[{"dateTimeOfEvent":"Nov 9, 2016 9:33:31 AM"}]`, which is not what you describe. I don't want you to post your entire application. I want you to debug your application until you can strip away all the parts that don't contribute to the issue and then post the [mcve].

Comment: Interesting that you got the date format as you describe "Nov 9, 2016 9:33:31 AM" because the format string I have in my example should output "2016-11-09 09:33:31 {your timezone}". Did you debug your code to see if it is definitely hitting the JsonSerializer? or have you just got a different simple date format in yours?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis if you compare my question detail to others asking a similar question then the detail is either more or similar. I really dont see what else you want me to add. The detail includes more than enough to give someone an idea of the problematic area. If you want to see another layer of the app specifically, then please ask for that. I dont appreciate negative comments and down votes on anyone's question or answer unless they are absolutely necessary, it just puts people off using this technical forum.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I was testing on 4.x. Spring has removed the `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` in that version, so it was falling back on `GsonHttpMessageConverter`. I tested with 3.x and it works fine, instantiating and using the `JsonSerializer`.

Comment: Other questions might just as bad. If you link them here (or add me to chat and do it there), I'll tell you the level of quality I (and Stack Overflow in general) expect. There's a reason we have this page: [mcve] and a close reason that reads _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced [...]. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: You obviously figured this out by fiddling with the one piece of configuration that you hadn't shown us. We're not about to start guessing. Useful questions contain all relevant information and yours originally didn't.

Comment: You seem to think that downvotes exist to _put people down_. No, they're a signal for quality. Your question wasn't useful the way it was presented. You can see some of the standards if you hover over the downvote/upvote buttons. More information can be found in the Help Center (or discuss it on Meta). You should start using your votes aggressively. It's one of the only ways we have to maintain the quality of the site.

Comment: Well I'll give you this, you're better than some who just down vote and run. I admire you for sticking by your vote with justifications. Its fine, I'm not interested in continuing the discussion on voting any further, thanks for your input either way, no sarcasm intended. Hopefully my answer will help others if they have a similar problem with class level serialisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was just an application level bean config overriding my class level annotations.

This is the updated version of the bean configuration for the jackson mappers, etc. Notice the additional `SimpleDateFormat` bean and `ObjectMapper` `dateFormat` property using it.

```
<bean id="jsonDateFromat" class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
    <constructor-arg value="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"/>
</bean>
<bean id="jaxbAnnIntrospector" class="org.codehaus.jackson.xc.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector" />
<bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper">
    <property name="serializationConfig.annotationIntrospector" ref="jaxbAnnIntrospector" />
    <property name="deserializationConfig.annotationIntrospector" ref="jaxbAnnIntrospector" />
    <property name="dateFormat" ref="jsonDateFromat"/>
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"
              p:objectMapper-ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

I removed all class level annotations as they were just ignored anyway because of this application level config.

This was fine for me as application level config fitted ok in the end, but it would be interesting to have a scenario where both were needed.

Here is the JSON after I made this change to the config:

```
[
 {
    "dateTimeOfEvent": "2016-11-09 14:19:20 GMT"
 },
 {
    "dateTimeOfEvent": "2016-11-09 14:25:15 GMT"
 }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not easy to get your issue with what you show here. However, i want to share my thought with you. Your serializer is implemented correctly. Here, you are using jackson library so that you just make serialization action by serialize json string to java object. I guess you can get the problem at this step. Make serialization you can do liks this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
//deserialize json to object
MyDomainObject domainObject = mapper.readValue("Your json file or json string", MyDomainObject.class);

//serialize object to json string
String jsonString = mapper.mapper.writeValueAsString(domainObject);
```

And date and other fields will be serialized correctly

I found the tutorial [Jackson Json Annotation Example](http://javabycode.com/java-core/json-tutorial/jackson-json-annotation-example.html) that also creates custom date serializer.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of this answer. If you can't reproduce the issue, flag/vote to close the question with that reason. They aren't trying to deserialize JSON, they're trying to serialize a POJO _to_ JSON.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis. I get the problem and I want to show both deserialize and serialize here. Maybe i made a typing mistake.